# How do I use cgsize make?

Tags: ios, cgsize

I have been trying to use `cgsizemake` as follows:

I'm trying to make the frame of my image a different size using `cgrectmake` instead of changing the coordinates.

So far I have tried

```
 maincharacter.frame = cgsizemake (14, 14);
```

but I keep getting the error

***assigning to cgrect from incompatible type CGsize***

Comment: FYI - Objective-C is case sensitive. Please use proper case in your questions to be clear.

Comment: In a frame you need to provide CGRECT. frame has a x-axis, y-axis, width and height. thats why "assigning to cgrect from incompatible type CGsize" comes.

Answer (score 19):

One solution would be:

```
CGRect frame = maincharacter.frame;
frame.size = CGSizeMake(14, 14);
maincharacter.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 14):

CGSize only accepts height and width

```
CGSize c=CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

If you want to set the frame size use CGRectMake

```
maincharacter.frame=CGRectMake(x-origin,y-origin, width, height);
```

Comment: What's the point of the variable `c` if you aren't going to use it? This answer doesn't show how to update a frame using CGSizeMake.

Answer (score 1):

maincharacter.frame must return (x, y, width, height) 4 parameters and CGSizeMake only have "width" and "height" 2 parameters. So You got an error. The solution is use frame.size, which returns 2 parameters to work with CGSizeMake(14, 14).

Answer (score 0):

To use the variable `c` which is of type `CGSize` you would call `c.0` and `c.1` for the height and width respectively. I don't know why they named those properties 0 and 1 but you will have to take that up with Dennis Ritchie

Here is an example usage of `CGSizeMake`:

```
        var makeSize =  CGSizeMake(size.0, size.1)
        let circ = SKShapeNode(ellipseOfSize: makeSize)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CGSize viewwidth;
    viewwidth=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
```

this will help you to get device current resolution using cgsize.

```
viewwidth.width or viewwidth.height
```

as above u can use it. and also as below code

```
rightslide=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, viewwidth.width, viewwidth.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

below is an example of using CGSizeMake in a UIScrollView

```
var mainScrollView: UIScrollView?
var numPages = 3

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //this gets the screen frames size
    var fm: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    //creates a UIScrollView programmatically
    self.mainScrollView = UIScrollView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, fm.size.width, fm.size.height))

    self.mainScrollView!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.mainScrollView!.frame.size.width, self.mainScrollView!.frame.size.height * CGFloat(numPages))
 }
```